# How to center an image and text underneath inside a div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to make a 4 split landing page with an icon and a text underneath it, centered both horizontally and vertically  inside each div. I tried various solutions, non of which seems to work, so i'm posting what i have so far. Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W8gs3/

HTML:

```
    <div id="rect1"> 

            <p><img src="icon.png"/></p>
            <p>Sound</p>

    </div>
    <div id="rect2">rect2</div>
    <br />
    <div id="rect3">rect3</div>
    <div id="rect4">rect4</div>
    <br />
```

CSS:

```
    /* CSS Document */

    html, body {
    width:   100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:     0;
    margin: 0;
    }

    div {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    float: left;
    }

    #rect1 {
        background: #0066FF;
    }

    #rect2 {
        background-color: #CC0033;
    }
    #rect3 {
        background-color: #669966;
    }
    #rect4 {
        background-color: #FFCC33;
    }
    br {
    clear:   left;
    }
```

Comment: add text-align: center; to your css

Comment: why did this get downvoted?  @Grumpy that won't vertically align it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an additional `div` into your html:

Sound

```
<div id="rect2" class="outer">
    <div class="inner">rect2</div>
</div>
<div id="rect3" class="outer">
    <div class="inner">rect3</div>
</div>
<div id="rect4" class="outer">
    <div class="inner">rect4</div>
</div>
```

You can use the following styles:

```
div.outer {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    float: left;
    display:table;
}
div.inner {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/W8gs3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want to align img to center, below is my suggestion

Make the img tag inline which you want to center align.

```
#rect1 p img {
display: inline;
width:30px;
height:30px;

}
#rect1 p  {
text-align:center;
}
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can make center the image and text using the below CSS. check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/W8gs3/15/)**.

```
#rect1, #rect1 p img {
    background: #0066FF;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
#rect1 p{
    margin:0;padding:0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only centers horizontaly

Comment: I've modified it now, will be horizontal and vertical center

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center; /*add this*if it is necessary in the middle of all the elements*/
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain your answer any :) explainations are better than code only answers

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

**HTML**

```
<section> 
<div id="rect1"> 
 <p><img src="icon.png"/></p>
 p>Sound</p>
</div>
<div id="rect2">rect2</div>
</section>
<section> 
<div id="rect3">rect3</div>
<div id="rect4">rect4</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:   100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:     0;
    margin: 0;
    }

    section{
        position:relative; height:50%; width:100%; display:table;
    }

    div {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

    #rect1 {
        background: #0066FF;
    }

    #rect2 {
        background-color: #CC0033;
    }
    #rect3 {
        background-color: #669966;
    }
    #rect4 {
        background-color: #FFCC33;
    }
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W8gs3/14/

Answer (score 0):

If ancient browser support is not an issue, you can use [css3 flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) as follows:

```
div {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8gs3/17/)